# Set Web Part Recommendation Settings in elements.xml or .webpart file

Tags: web-part, visual-web-part, elements-xml

Is it possible to set the Recommendation Settings of a WebPart in the elements.xml or .webpart file? Just like you can do with Group, Title and Description...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify `QuickAddGroups` in the Elements.xml like this:

```
<File Type="GhostableInLibrary" Url="AuthoredListFilter.webpart">
    <Property Name="Group" Value="$Resources:spscore,FiltersWebPartGroup;" />
    <Property Name="QuickAddGroups" Value=";#Filters;#My Site: Middle Right;#My Site: Middle Left;#My Site: Bottom;#" />
</File>
```